# OpenGL Texture Mapping distorts image

Tags: c#, opengl, tao-framework

So, I'm just trying to draw a texture to two triangles that are the same size as the viewport, but it breaks up the image and distorts it, I have tried resizing the image file and everything, but nothing seems to work. Below is the code that maps the texture and draws the triangles.

```
 public void Render()
    {
        Texture texture = _textureManager.Get("splash");
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.Id);

        double height = 720;
        double width = 1280;

        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        double z = 0;

        float topUV = 0;
        float bottomUV = 1;
        float leftUV = 0;
        float rightUV = 1;

        Gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES);
        {
            Gl.glTexCoord2d(leftUV, topUV);
            Gl.glVertex3d(x - width, y + height, z);
            Gl.glTexCoord2d(rightUV, topUV);
            Gl.glVertex3d(x + width, y + height, z);
            Gl.glTexCoord2d(leftUV, bottomUV);
            Gl.glVertex3d(x - width, y - height, z);

            Gl.glTexCoord2d(rightUV, topUV);
            Gl.glVertex3d(x + width, y + height, z);
            Gl.glTexCoord2d(rightUV, bottomUV);
            Gl.glVertex3d(x + width, y - height, z);
            Gl.glTexCoord2d(leftUV, bottomUV);
            Gl.glVertex3d(x - width, y - height, z);
        }
        Gl.glEnd();

    }
```

Here is the original image:
[image]

And here's the result:
[image]

The image is 1920 x 1080, and the viewport is 1280 x 720, but I'm not too sure that matters because I have tried resizing the image and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is this a square texture? If the image is 1920x1080 that's far from square. And before you are tempted to change that to "rectangular" texture, you should know that there's already something called a rectangle texture in GL that is different from a 2D texture (rectangle textures use non-normalized texture coordinates).

Comment: Nevertheless, I suspect part of your problem might be from the fact that the dimensions are not a power-of-two. In addition to not using normalized texture coordinates, a rectangle texture will also overcome issues with that. *Can you try resizing the texture to be a power-of-two (say 1024x1024) as a test?*

Comment: Resizing the image to 1024 x 1024 fixed the issue. So, in order to draw the image in its original resolution, I'm kind of confused as to what I have to change?

Comment: Can you add a little bit more information to your question? For instance what the values of `GL_VERSION`, `GL_RENDERER` and `GL_VENDOR` are at run-time? You can get these values by calling `glGetString (...)`. In order for me to answer this, that information would really help.

Comment: Renderer: AMD Radeon R7 200 Series  |

Vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.   |

Version: 4.4.13084 Compatibility Profile Context 14.301.1001.0   |

Comment: I actually don't know why using a power-of-two sized texture fixes the problem in that case. Beginning with OpenGL 2.0, NPOT (non-power-of-two) textures are natively supported. The only thing I can think of is some limitation with TAO, but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I ended up cutting the image in half down the center and just loading two images, and then I used four triangles. This may not be the most elegant solution, but it works just fine. I'm guessing it had to do with the dimensions of the image. (I also changed the parameters for the texture coordinates and all the vertices so that it is more straight forward in the context of Stack Overflow).

```
public void Render()
    {
        //Draw Left Half
        Texture texture = _textureManager.Get("splash1");
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.Id);


        Gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES);
        {
            Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0);//top left
            Gl.glVertex2f(-1280 , 720);

            Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0);//middle top
            Gl.glVertex2f(0, 720);

            Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);//bottom left
            Gl.glVertex2f(-1280, -720);


            Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);//bottom left
            Gl.glVertex2f(-1280, -720);

            Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0);//middle right top
            Gl.glVertex2f(0, 720);

            Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1);//bottom middle
            Gl.glVertex2f(0, -720);
        }
        Gl.glEnd();

        //Draw Right Half
        texture = _textureManager.Get("splash2");
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.Id);

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES);
        {
            Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0);//middle top
            Gl.glVertex2f(0, 720);

            Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0);//top right
            Gl.glVertex2f(1280, 720);

            Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);//bottom middle
            Gl.glVertex2f(0, -720);

            Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0);//top right
            Gl.glVertex2f(1280, 720);

            Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);//bottom middle
            Gl.glVertex2f(0, -720);

            Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1);//bottom right
            Gl.glVertex2f(1280, -720);
        }
        Gl.glEnd();
    }
```